# ReactJS: We can convert string to html, but how to modify the html code during the process?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In the comment section of my forum-like website, users can attach files in a post.

When making comments, users can edit using Rich Text Editor and quote a file attached in the post;

When users make a comment quoting a file, the data stored in backend database after the comment is submitted will be a string that contains html tags, example:

```
const commentContent = "
<p><br></p>
<p>This is a comment</p>
<blockquote>
  BJFC123_003.jpeg
</blockquote>
<p>Hi John, this is the file that I mentioned about</p>
<p>please click to download the file</p>
<p><br></p>
"
```

when other users read the post, the comment is fetched and the above text is loaded like the below way to convert pure string into actual html for displaying:

```
<div 
    className="ql-editor" 
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: commentContent }} 
  {...otherProps} 
/>
```

Now, instead of this simple scenario, I need to make a twist:

when loading the comment, instead of loading html as described in the original text, I need to add `onclick` event to all `blockquote` tags.

So the actual loaded elements in the DOM should be:

```
<p><br></p>
<p>This is a comment</p>
<blockquote onclick={myCustomMethod(filename)}>
  BJFC123_003.jpeg
</blockquote>
<p>Hi John, this is the file that I mentioned about</p>
<p>please click to download the file</p>
<p><br></p>
```

Here,

`myCustomMethod()`is a function defined in the comments component

`filename`will be equal to `"BJFC123_003.jpeg"`

It is easy to extract the file name from the string `commentContent`, but how to make such a modification when converting from string to actual html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add onclick event to a string rendered by dangerouslysetInnerHtml in reactjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109790/how-to-add-onclick-event-to-a-string-rendered-by-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-reac)